# Running (Executing) EcmaScript in phpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

Is there any way to run Ecmascript (JS without DOM) scripts locally in PhpStorm and see result in console? (Without running a browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm [supports](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) [running and debugging](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html), install the Node.js plug-in from `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Plugins`.